# Swift UI multiple Picker with "empty" and 0...9

Tags: swiftui, picker

i want to create a picker with three numbers each from 0..9 and "empty" to select, and then getten these values liek number1 number2 and number3

found a way wo use with 0..9 but how can i use also a empty blank selection can have the value of empty

regards Alex

Comment: Please add whatever (minimal and relevant) code you already have

Answer (score 1):

I have made a quick example below of how you would did this. It allows you to select any number, and the empty value is marked as `nil`. This should make it much easier to get a value from, rather than `number1 number2 and number3`, etc.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var selection: Int?
    private var formattedSelection: String {
        selection != nil ? String(selection!) : "Empty"
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Selection:  \(formattedSelection)")
            
            Picker("Select number", selection: $selection) {
                Text("Empty").tag(nil as Int?)
                
                // Ranges from 0 to 9
                ForEach(0 ..< 10) { value in
                    Text(String(value)).tag(value as Int?)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How can i use the "selection" later on ? it stays on 0

Comment: @BigAL82 You can use `selection` at any point. If it’s not looking like it’s changing, that may be because you could be passing it to another view. In that case you would use a binding.

Comment: @BigAL82 Do you need more help, or did you get it working? If you are having problem, let me know (otherwise you can just mark the answer as accepted)